# WTForms: test whether field is filled out

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm having trouble with what I thought would be a very simple task in WTForms: checking to see if a field has had any data entered in it. It seems that the data method returns different results depending on the type of field, so I can't use it generically to test this.

I'm using this in a Flask app. In my forms declaration, I have:

```
title = StringField('Title')
signed = RadioField('Signed?', choices = [('Y','yes'),('N','no')])
```

Then, in my views.py, after an "if form.is_submitted()":

```
print('Title raw_data is %r' % form.title.raw_data)
print('Title data is %r' % form.title.data)
if form.title.raw_data:
    print ("Title raw data is True")
if form.title.data:
    print ("Title data is True")

 print('Signed raw_data is %r' % form.signed.raw_data)
 print('Signed data is %r' % form.signed.data)
 if form.signed.raw_data:
     print ("Signed raw data is True")
 if form.signed.data:
     print ("Signed data is True")
```

When I run this and fill out neither field in the form, I get:

```
Title raw_data is ['']
Title data is ''
Title raw data is True
Signed raw_data is []
Signed data is 'None'
Signed data is True
```

That is, form.title.data returns the empty string, so I can use this for a test; form.signed.data returns the string 'None', rather than None, so it fails the "if form.signed.data" test. Thus I have to use form.signed.raw_data, which returns an empty list, which is False. But I can't use raw_data in all instances, because form.title.raw_data doesn't return an empty list, it returns a list consisting of the empty string, which is *not* True

Is there a way I can test if any kind of field is filled out, or do I have to switch between data and raw_data depending on the kind of field? This is counterintuitive and confusing.

Comment: In your model, you can set `blank=False`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find this in any documentation--can you clarify what this is supposed to do, and where it's coming from?

I see there's an "allow_blank" and a "blank_text" in the Appengine extension, but I'm not using Appengine.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's a Django function. With WTF, you would use validators. Take a look at the docs here: [http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#wtforms.validators.DataRequired](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#wtforms.validators.DataRequired). If you can post your `forms.py` file, I can give you better direction.

Comment: Thanks #joshlsullivan I appreciate your help. I confess that I'm not clear from the docs how validators would work here. The point is, neither of these is required, so I don't want to validate them. I just want to be able to tell if they _have_ been filled in, in which case I'll construct a database query using them, but if they're not filled in, it's fine, I just won't use them for my query. My actual form is bigger, but for this test case, the bits I quoted from my forms.py do the job--my "title" and "signed" lines from the first code excerpt. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In `raw_data`, values for a form field are [collected in a list](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.1/wtforms/fields/core.py#L284).

You want to work with `data` because its value is [processed to its python representation](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.1/wtforms/fields/core.py#L287). Most fields subclassing `wtforms.fields.core.Field` implements their own `process_formdata` method which fulfills this.

Start by implementing a helper function that checks field data like so:

```
def is_filled(data):
   if data == None:
      return False
   if data == '':
      return False
   if data == []:
      return False
   return True
```

**Note that** data starts out set to the default value if a default value is specified in the field schema. In this case using `raw_data` is more correct.

```
def is_filled(raw_data):
   try:
       value = raw_data[0]
       if value == '':
          return False
   except (IndexError, TypeError):
       return False
   return True
```

Tests:

```
>>> is_filled(None)
False
>>> is_filled([])
False
>>> is_filled(['',]) 
False
```

Comment: In the first example, an empty string, None and an empty array would evaluate to false so a ternary operator `is_filled = True if data else False` would work just fine.

Comment: @EndermanAPM You're right. I tend towards _explicit is better than implicit_ in these kind of scenarios.

Comment: I usually gravitate to doing stuff with as less complexity as possible. It's true that a dev not used to Python might understand quicker the function but another that is usually a Python dev will not need to check what does the function. This is a bit of a stretch, because at the end the function name is self descriptive and just a few lines long but you get the gist.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this helps. First, in my example, the RadioField does _not_ have a default value specified; you said that using raw_data would be correct in this case. But secondly and more to the point, your suggestion would still require me to use a different function for some fields than others, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. But even if I had to use a different function for a default field (which makes a certain amount of sense), in my case—without a default—I do apparently need different functions for the two cases, b/c the RadioField example doesn't work. Thx.

Comment: To address your first concern, I meant that using `raw_data` is correct if there are default values for your fields. The only other way is _which is less direct_ is to patch a method onto base field. For your second question, `RadioField`  `raw_data` should be `None` if it's not filled and indexing it should lead to a TypeError. I will add that to the pre-condition. Thanks for pointing that out.