# Flask-SQLAlchemy : Apply filter only if value to compare is not empty

Tags: flask

I'm working on a small web-app that includes a filter with around 10/15 different fields,
since the user doesn't have to fill all the fields in order to be able to post the form, I implemented the below logic in order to avoid filtering the database with empty strings or values and obtain 0 results.

```
if not form.Price_from.data == "" and not form.Price_from.data == None:           
    Posts_filtered = Posts_filtered.filter(Post.Price >= form.Price_from.datas)
```

By doing this, I filter the column Post. Price only if the field form.Price_from field contains a value.

Since I have 10-15 fields, you can imagine that I have a lot of lines doing the same thing and I really do not like it. Since I'd like to add more fields in the future, my question is if there is a more efficient way to perform this action?
Do you think it would be faster to implement it with js? By doing that I should not need to send a post request every time and I'd save time.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a helper function and loop through every field:

```
def is_filled(raw_data):
   try:
       value = raw_data[0]
       if value == '':
          return False
   except (IndexError, TypeError):
       return False
   return True
```

(use raw_data from the field instead of data for this function)

you can more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47450458/11699898